# Integration of Frenet-Serret differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

Are there programs available in *Mathematica* or other related sources where third order Frenet-Serret equations are numerically integrated to find coordinates in 3-space?

Curvature/torsion given as functions of arc length, with boundary condition as: tangent, bi-normal and normal directions along orthogonal Cartesian axes at origin start point

#### Edit

(Temporary edit to communicate to Michael a small error at my end; shall delete)

```
f = {Cos[s/Sqrt[2]], Sin[s/Sqrt[2]], s/Sqrt[2]}; 
fssys = FrenetSerretSystem[f, s]
x0 = f /. s -> 0 
κτ = First @ fssys /. s -> 0 
tnb0 = Last @ fssys /. s -> 0 
rhs[{κ_, τ_}] := {{0, κ, 0}, {-κ, 0, τ}, {0, -τ, 0}} 
sol = 
  NDSolve[
    {{TNB'[s] == rhs[κτ].TNB[s], TNB[0] == tnb0}, 
     {X'[s] == {1, 0, 0}.TNB[s], X[0] == x0}}, 
    {TNB, X}, {s, 0, 2 Sqrt[2] Pi}] 
ParametricPlot3D[X[s] /. sol, {s, 0, 2Sqrt[2] Pi}]
```

Comment: This demonstration does it in real time (via `Dynamic` and Euler's method, not `NDSolve`): http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AerialTourOfDifferentialGeometry/

Comment: Apparently you've forgotten how to format code :) See this advice: "You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful"

Comment: Oh, maybe it's because I left off `Simplify`: `FrenetSerretSystem[f, s] // Simplify` gets rid of the `s` b/c the curvature and torsion are constant.

Comment: Oops, this is wrong: `κτ = First@fssys /. s -> 0`.  It should be `κτ = First@fssys`.

Comment: Forgot I answered this one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39137/finding-a-3d-curve-from-torsion-and-curvature-with-ndsolve/39157#39157

Comment: Your answer is proving to be very useful. Using this program for post below.  Is it possible to check hyperboloid solution given there? http://math.stackexchange.com/users/95860/narasimham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toy example:

```
f = {Cos[s/Sqrt[2]], Sin[s/Sqrt[2]], s/Sqrt[2]};
fssys = FrenetSerretSystem[f, s];
```

Data:

```
x0 = f /. s -> 0;            (* initial point of curve *)
κτ = First@fssys;            (* {curvature, torsion} *)
tnb0 = Last@fssys /. s -> 0; (* Initial condition of T-N-B *)
```

Solution:

```
ClearAll[rhs];
rhs[{κ_, τ_}] :={    (* right-hand side of ODE *)
   {0, κ, 0},
   {-κ, 0, τ},
   {0, -τ, 0}};

{sol} = NDSolve[{
    {TNB'[s] == rhs[κτ].TNB[s], TNB[0] == tnb0},
    {X'[s] == {1, 0, 0}.TNB[s], X[0] == x0}},
  {TNB, X}, {s, 0, 2 Sqrt[2] Pi}]
```

Plot:

```
ParametricPlot3D[X[s] /. sol, {s, 0, 2 Sqrt[2] Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example:

```
x0 = {0, 0, 0};                   (* initial point of curve *)
κτ = {2 + 3 Cos[4 s], 2 Sin[s]};  (* {curvature,torsion} *)
tnb0 = IdentityMatrix[3];         (* Initial condition of T-N-B *)
{sol} = NDSolve[{{TNB'[s] == rhs[κτ].TNB[s], TNB[0] == tnb0},
   {X'[s] == {1, 0, 0}.TNB[s], X[0] == x0}},
  {TNB, X}, {s, 0, 40}];
ParametricPlot3D[X[s] /. sol, {s, 0, 40}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. A small IC error is troubling, please   check   the same ;              f={Cos[s/Sqrt[2]],Sin[s/Sqrt[2]],s/Sqrt[2]};
fssys=FrenetSerretSystem[f,s]
x0=f/.s->0
\[Kappa]\[Tau]=First@fssys/.s->0
tnb0=Last@fssys/.s->0
rhs[{\[Kappa]_,\[Tau]_}]:={{0,\[Kappa],0},{-\[Kappa],0,\[Tau]},{0,-\[Tau],0}}
sol=NDSolve[{{TNB'[s]==rhs[\[Kappa]\[Tau]].TNB[s],TNB[0]==tnb0},{X'[s]=={1,0,0}.TNB[s],X[0]==x0}},{TNB,X},{s,0,2 Sqrt[2] Pi}]
ParametricPlot3D[X[s]/.sol,{s,0,2 Sqrt[2] Pi}]    Regards

Comment: @Narasimham I can't copy your code b/c you didn't paste it between backquotes.  Some characters are missing and it gives errors.

Comment: Hope it gives clue of missing chars.