# Constructing a 2D curve from a curvature function dynamically

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, differential-geometry

I want to plot a curve starting from its curvature function and some initial conditions. This code generates a 2D curve with a given curvature (fun) and some initial conditions:

```
curveOfCurvatureK[
    fun_, a_: 0, {c_: 0, d_: 0, e_: 0}, {smin_: - 10, smax_: 10}, optsnd___][t_] :=
  Module[{x, y, θ, s}, 
    eqs = {x'[s] == Cos[θ[s]], 
    y'[s] == Sin[θ[s]], θ'[s] == fun[s], x[a] == c, 
    y[a] == d, θ[a] == e};
    sol = NDSolve[eqs, {x, y, θ}, {s, smin, smax}, optsnd];
    {x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]]]
```

Then executing:

```
points = {{0, 2}, {1, 3}, {1/2, 1}, {3/2, 4}, {2, 2}, {5/2, 2}, {3,0}};
k := Interpolation[points];
GraphicsGrid[
  {{Plot[k[x], {x, 0, 3}], 
    ParametricPlot[
      Evaluate[curveOfCurvatureK[k, 0, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 3}]][x], {x, 0, 3}]}}]
```

I get the plot of the curvature next to the corresponding curve obtained. I want to know how to make the same thing but interactive. That is, generate a curvature function on the left that can be moved, like:

```
DynamicModule[{points = {{0.`, 2}, {0.5`, 3}, {1.`, 1}, {1.5`, 4}, {2.`, 2}, {2.5`, 2}, {3.`, 2}}}, 
  LocatorPane[
     Dynamic[points], 
     Dynamic[
       Plot[Interpolation[points, x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}]]]]
```

and then obtain (dynamically) the corresponding 2D curve on the right.

How can I do that? I have already searched related problems and could not find anything to make it work.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39137/finding-a-3d-curve-from-torsion-and-curvature-with-ndsolve

Answer (score 4):

one possibility:

```
DynamicModule[{points = {{0., 2}, {0.5, 3}, {1., 1}, {1.5, 4}, {2., 2}, {2.5, 2}, {3., 2}}, 
  intF = Interpolation[{{0., 2}, {0.5, 3}, {1., 1}, {1.5, 4}, {2., 2}, {2.5, 2}, {3., 2}}]},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[points, (points = #; intF = Interpolation[#]) &],
   Dynamic @ Row[{ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x, intF[x]}], {x, 0, Max[points[[All, 1]]]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {-5, 5}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 1 -> {40, 30}], 
     ParametricPlot[Evaluate[curveOfCurvatureK[intF, 0, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 3}][x]], {x, 0, 3}, 
      Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}/2, ImageSize -> 1 -> 60]}, Spacer[5]], 
  {{0, -5}, {8, 5}}]]
```

[image]