# Finding unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for interpolated function

Tags: vector-calculus, differential-geometry

As an extension of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240824/adding-texture-to-tube), is it possible to find the unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for an interpolated function? eg

```
pts = {{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 4, 1}};
f = Interpolation[Transpose[{N@Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[pts] - 1)], pts}]];
```

`Length@Last@FrenetSerretSystem[f[t], t]` outputs `2`.

Motivation is as [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240824/adding-texture-to-tube).

Comment: You can either use `NDSolve[]` on the Frenet-Serret equations (like what was done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39157)), or construct a [Bishop frame](https://doi.org/10.2307/2319846) instead (like what was done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169836)).

Comment: @J. M. thank you, I'll have a go

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First we get you interpolating function:

```
pts = {{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 4, 1}};
f = Interpolation[Transpose[{N@Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[pts] - 1)], pts}]];
```

Then we calculate the tangent, nornal and binormal:

```
utan[t_] = f'[t]/Norm[f'[t]];
normal[t_] = Module[{fu, x}, fu[x_] = f''[x] - (f''[x].utan[x]) utan[x]; 
   fu[t]/Norm[fu[t]]];
binormal[t_] = Cross[utan[t], normal[t]];
```

And finally we make an interactive plot:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{ParametricPlot3D[f[x], {x, 0, 1}],
   Graphics3D[{Arrow[{f[t], f[t] + utan[t]}], Red, 
     Arrow[{f[t], f[t] + normal[t]}], Green, 
     Arrow[{f[t], f[t] + binormal[t]}]}]
   }, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}, {-2, 2}}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: great!  thanks :)